# using > /dev/null outputs ambiguous number to console

Tags: php, bash, command-line, terminal

So I need to run a background process via the command line (using `exec`) while also passing parameters to the executed **PHP** script.

Before I continue, I will show my script in order to better understand what is going on:

```
var_dump($argv);
exit;
```

To get the parameters to be passed was simple, all that was required was:

```
$ php -q test.php foo bar
```

This, as expected, would output:

```
array(2){
    [0] => string(11) "test.php"
    [1] => string(3) "foo"
    [2] => string(3) "bar"
}
```

However, in order to run the script asynchronously, I needed the command to be:

```
$ php -q test.php foo bar >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

But for some reason, it outputs an arbitrary number similar to this every single time I execute the command:

```
[1] 79401
```

I've been searching around for a solution, but cannot find anything on the matter at hand.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: That's the PID of the process that you're sending to background, not an arbitrary number.

Comment: @danlor ohhh that makes sense. But why would it output that as opposed to what is expected from the actual PHP script?

Comment: It would output both, the job ID and the PID and the output to `stdout` and `stderr`, since them are still attached to the parent shell. However, note that `stdin` is detached. Since you have redirected the output (both `stdout` and `stderr`)  to `/dev/null`, it only will display job ID and PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As danlor stated, it is the process id of the PHP script.
Using '&' at the end of a command means, that the shell should run the command in background, so shells tell you the PID of the process.
You also suppress any output to stdout and stderr by using "> /dev/null" and "2> /dev/null".

Answer (score 0):

You can send the command to background, then send output to /dev/null

/bin/bash -c "php -q test.php foo bar &" 2>&1 >/dev/null